# IntelliJ Spring boot, hot deploy doesn't run

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I develop an application on IntelliJ with Spring Boot framework.

My backend is in Java and my front in Javascript.

I use Maven for the compiler.

BUT, when i change anything in a javascript class and use "CTL+SHIFT+F9" to recompile my class, this class disappear of my front deployment....

For this moment, i always do maven clean and maven compile to get my class in a front

How to hot deploy my javascript class change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need the option "Update classes and resources". You should be able find this option in your spring boot Run/Debug configuration in the Running Application Update Policies section and change `On frame deactivation` to `Update classes and resources`

Comment: I already tried it change... but it doesn't work.
Finally, il re-install my intelliJ ide. It's ok now :-)